# AWS CLI not listing policies attached to role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I followed the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html) to set up and remove a python lambda function (and associated AWS resources).

When I try to clean up the function, role-policy and role, the instructions failed because the CLI does not manage to find the attached role policies. In particular, if I run:

```
aws iam list-role-policies --role-name myrolename
```

... I get an output of:

```
{
    "PolicyNames": []
}
```

But when I look up the same role in the AWS console, `I can see the policy is there.`

[image]

So what is going on here? Is this an AWS bug (CLI version aws-cli/2.1.33 Python/3.9.2 Darwin/20.4.0 source/x86_64), or am I muddled up here somehow?

Comment: added a solution which tells as to why your command wont work for inline policies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i can see from the image, its a managed policy and unfortunately [list-role-policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-role-policies.html) only  Lists the names of the inline policies that are embedded in the specified IAM role.

[Doc says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-role-policies.html)

> An IAM role can also have managed policies attached to it. To list the managed policies that are attached to a role, use [ListAttachedRolePolicies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-attached-role-policies.html)

use this for example

```
aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name SecurityAuditRole
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I suspect that under the hood `delete-role-policy` is only using `list-role-policies`. I've opened an issue here https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6139